# Combobox with remote store but query locally

Tags: extjs, extjs7

I have a combo that binds to a rest proxy store. I want to load the data remotely, but once it's loaded, if user search within the combo, I don't want to query the server, but just locally against the store.

If I set queryMode: 'local', it never loads data from remote server. This is misleading, since the property name suggests that it is related to the query action itself, not the store.

Any workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add some example or fiddle to reproduce this behaviour ?

Comment: Sounds like you need to set [autoLoad](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/classic/Ext.data.Store.html#cfg-autoLoad) on your store or load your store manually but keep `queryMode: 'local'`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a store already loaded remotely to populate your combo, you can use [chained store](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.4.0/guides/tutorials/grid_tutorial/data_manipulation/chained_stores/ext.data.chainedstore.html). Then you can have your combo set to **queryMode: 'local'** and define its store like this ('storename' must be a valid [storeId](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.4.0/modern/Ext.data.AbstractStore.html#cfg-storeId)):

```
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    editable: true,
    queryMode: 'local',
    forceSelection: true,
    store: {
        type: 'chained',
        source: 'storename'
    }
}
```

Basically it creates a virtual copy of the remotely loaded store that can have it's own filters and sorters without affecting the original (source) store. And this you can filter locally.

This is very useful if you use the same store in multiple comboboxes. With this approach you will load the data only once, but you can have different filters at the same time in different combos. I had this problem, and it was very annoying, without chained stores, if the user filters somewhere to 'abc', all other combos were filtered accordingly and this is definitely not desirable in most of the cases.